# Create an Android Target with x86 as ABIs

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i run android target list, I see only ABIs=armeabi, how to add an android target which has an ABIs=x86. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

When you build from source you can select the target using the lunch command:

```
You're building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. full-eng
     2. full_x86-eng
     3. vbox_x86-eng
     4. full_maguro-userdebug
     5. full_tuna-userdebug
     6. full_panda-eng

Which would you like? [full-eng]
```

Then after selecting the desired lunch combo, do

```
$ make
```

Comment: My sources have Makefiles and it is not an ndk-build.